# TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable error while Parsing from HTML

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote script to parse the information from one website using BeautifulSoup, but I have problems with it.

As seen from the code, in the commented section for websiteReq it gives me error of

**raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: Forbidden**

I have searched on internet and usage of Request was recommended. I tried it as seen in the code, but I get error of **TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable** .

I would like to know where I'm doing wrong. Thank you. Have a nice day.

*Code:*

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jul 23 22:39:05 2019

@author: Nijat
"""

try:
    # For Python 3.0 and later
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to Python 2's urllib2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv 
from datetime import datetime
import requests

webData = []

#websiteReq = ['https://boss.az/vacancies'] #FORBIDDEN ERROR WITH THIS 

websiteReq = Request('https://boss.az/vacancies', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) #Request not iterable

#for pg in websiteReq: #ERROR OCCURS HERE
page = urlopen(websiteReq)
soupping = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser').encode("utf-8")

takingTitle = soupping.find_all('h3', attrs={'class':'results-i-title'})
takingCompany = soupping.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'results-i-company'})
takingDescription = soupping.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'results-i-summary'})

nameofVac = takingTitle.text.strip()
nameofComp = takingCompany.text.strip()
nameofDescript = takingDescription.text.strip()

webData.append((nameofVac, nameofComp, nameofDescript))

with open('Vacancies.csv','a') as csvfile:
    writingtocsv = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for nameofVac, nameofComp in webData:
        writingtocsv.writerow([nameofVac, nameofComp, nameofDescript,datetime.now()])
```

Updated Code from answer:

So, the result gives me all the parsed information from first page which was about 30 vacancies. If you would like to add other pages, just do +=

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

for t in range(28):
    url = "https://boss.az/vacancies?action=index&controller=vacancies&only_path=true&page={}&type=vacancies".format(t)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

    titles = [i.text for i in soup.select('.results-i-title')]
    #print(titles)
    companies = [i.text for i in soup.select('.results-i-company')]
    #print(companies)
    summaries = [i.text for i in soup.select('.results-i-summary')]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(titles, companies, summaries)), columns = ['Title', 'Company', 'Summary'])
df.to_csv(r'Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

However, it doesn't read all the pages now. Any clue why?

Comment: What do you want to do with that loop? Request will simply return the request object representation of that url

Comment: Take the information from website by using HTML classes which are takingTitle, takingCompany and takingDescription. In order to take them, I had to use BeautifulSoup with html.parser by opening URL. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: If so then simply remove the loop and it'll work fine

Comment: Ankit, but I want to take all the information from the website. If I remove the loop it will only take HTML class once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find_all returns lists so you can't do .text on any variable returned by that. I would use requests and as your selectors return lists of equal length zip them and chuck into a dataframe with pandas. You can then write to csv.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://boss.az/vacancies'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
titles = [i.text for i in soup.select('.results-i-title')]
companies = [i.text for i in soup.select('.results-i-company')]
summaries = [i.text for i in soup.select('.results-i-summary')]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(titles, companies, summaries)), columns = ['Title', 'Company', 'Summary'])
df.to_csv(r'Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

Comment: Amazing and best answer. Works like a charm. Accepted your answer as a good one.

Comment: Could you please check the updated code? Where's the problem?

Comment: because you are overwriting the lists each time. You want to append to master lists then flatten and zip though you may find lists are not of same length across different pages. You should open that as a new question however as the question when I saw it was without a loop and the url was as per in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Request() returns you an object of class Request. It is not iterable. You should use some methods from this class to return text/content. Then you can parse it with BS.

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
>>> print(response.content)
b'{\n  "args": {}, \n  "headers": {\n    "Accept": "*/*", \n    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", \n    "Host": "httpbin.org", \n    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.9.1"\n  }, \n  "origin": "95.56.82.136", \n  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"\n}\n'
>>> response.json()
{'headers': {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.9.1', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'Accept': '*/*'}, 'args': {}, 'origin': '95.56.82.136', 'url': 'https://httpbin.org/get'}
>>> response.headers
{'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Server': 'nginx', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Length': '237', 'Date': 'Wed, 23 Dec 2015 17:56:46 GMT'}
>>> response.headers.get('Server')
'nginx'
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not the answer for my question.

Comment: @NijatMursali, Request() returns you an object of class Request. It is not iterable. You should use some methods from this class to return text/content. Then you can parse it with BS.

Answer (score 0):

Just passing by... 
Instead of using Beautiful Soup, maybe just use a regex? 
Like so:

```py
import re
import requests

data = []
s = requests.Session()
page_html = s.get('https://en.boss.az/vacancies',
                  headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text

regex_logic = re.compile(
    r'<h3 class="results-i-title">.*?<\/h3><a target=.*?class="results-i-company" href=.*?>((\w|\s)+)')
myiter = re.finditer(regex_logic, page_html)
while True:
    try:
        data.append(next(myiter).group(1))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Here is the  code in  greater detail, with quite a long regex.

The idea is to fetch the text of the GET request, and create an iterator with  th regex. I used your example to get the Company Name I believe. You then want to loop through the iterator.

If you want the data from all the pages, just look for the number of pages and edit the get url with the page number as the logic goes for this particular website.

Comment: Could you please describe it more? How to parse the website with that? Edit your code a bit please.